# How to delete an obsolete RSS feed and newsgroup server in Thunderbird in Windows 10?

Tags: thunderbird, rss, newsgroups

Problem exists in both versions 91.3 and 102.7 of Thunderbird running on Windows 10.

I want to delete a discontinued RSS feed and a newsgroup server from Thunderbird. Selecting each and pressing “DEL“ doesn't delete them. Right-clicking each offers no removal option as the linked screenshots will show. Posting a request for a solution in the [Thunderbird support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1402868) resulted in no functional solution. How do I remove those?

[image]

Comment: Are these perhaps _accounts_? Dunno if you can have multiple RSS accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How to delete obsolete RSS feed?

> - Tools > Account Settings or Menu icon > Options > Account Settings
> - select the RSS Feed mail account you want to remove
> - Click the 'Account Actions' menu on the bottom left side of the window.
> - Click 'Remove Account'.
> - Click 'OK'.
> - Click 'OK' again to exit the Account Settings window.

Source: [rss feed remove](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1086038)

Answer (score -1):

> Tools > Account Settings or Menu icon > Options > Account Settings etc.

Do not think this is an answer to this question, for the question is, as I can see it, not about removing (Thunderbird) accounts, but about removing RSS feeds (or RSS feed servers) and about removing newsgroups (or newsgroup servers), managed within these Thunderbird accounts.

As to RSS feeds, a way to remove these is by:

- (within Thunderbird's Folder panel to the left,) clicking on "Blogs & News Feeds"
- clicking on "Manage Feed Subscriptions", within the right panel, to the upper left
- within the tree structure appearing then, clicking on the RSS feed concerned (at deepest level within this structure, for each feed individually, could be one to several levels)
- clicking the "Remove" button near the lower left of this panel to get rid of the feed subscription
- clicking OK.

Do not know about removing newsgroups (newsgroup servers), but think it is not a wild guess this could be done likewise.